# how can i delete a image from isolatedstorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

i have a listbox which is binded to images it gets from isolated storage here is how i get those images...

```
     foreach (string fileName in fileStorage.GetFileNames("images//*.*"))
            {
                if (fileName == null)
                    break;
                string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine("images", fileName);
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream imageStream = fileStorage.OpenFile(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var imageSource = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);
                    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);
                    vltBitmapImage.Add(bitmapImage);

                }
            }
          this.vaultbox.ItemsSource = vltBitmapImage;
```

now i want to delete the selected image(multiple can be selected)

```
     if (vaultbox.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Files will be deleted forever", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (m == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
                vaultbox.SelectedIndex = -1;
            else if(m==MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (BitmapImage item in vaultbox.SelectedItems)
                {
                    //what should i do here?
                }
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No file selected");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store a connection Image-File name.

For example:

```
public class ImageToName
{
   public BitmapImage Image {get;set;}
   public string FileName {get;set;}
}
```

A list will be changed to:

```
List<ImageToName> vltBitmapImage = new List<ImageToName>();
```

And fill the list in this way:

```
 //read file
 var imageSource = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);
 BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
 bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);
 var item = new ImageToName {Image = bitmapImage , Name = fileName };
 vltBitmapImage.Add(item);
```

and you need to change `ListBox` Declaration

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
   <Image Source={Binding Image}/>
   </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

So, you will be able to get File names from selected items.

Comment: i forgot to mention currently my list is like this....
List<BitmapImage> vltBitmapImage = new List<BitmapImage>();